# Do not display item from recordset in form in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Say I have a table that has six names:

```
Barry
Terry
Larry
Gary
Barry
Harry
```

I then have a form that uses a textboxes to display all of the names.

But if I didn't want to show the name Gary, how would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exclude the row from the form's recordsource:

```
select * from table where name <> 'gary'
```

Comment: Thanks! New to Access, didn't know about the query builder.